# How to read tetrads (groups of four integers) and save it in 2d array?

Tags: c, arrays, 2d

This is the function that I have written:

```
int read_data(int (*p)[0][0])
{
    int i,j;
    for (i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<1;j++)
        {
            printf("give first number:");
            scanf("%d",&(*p)[i][j]);
            printf("give second number:");
            scanf("%d",&(*p)[i][j]);
            printf("give third number:");
            scanf("%d",&(*p)[i][j]);
            printf("give forth number:");
            scanf("%d",&(*p)[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for (i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
            printf("%d [%d],[%d]\n",(*p)[i][j],i,j);
            printf("%d [%d],[%d]\n",(*p)[i][j],i,j);
            printf("%d [%d],[%d]\n",(*p)[i][j],i,j);
            printf("%d [%d],[%d]\n",(*p)[i][j],i,j);
        }
    }
}
```

I have to solve an exercise. One part of the problem is to read tetrads of integers (groups of four integers) and save it in an array. I tried many different approaches, but none seem to work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very simple solution.

Numbers are assigned directly in the 2 dimension array in a single scanf (you can use indices but it is not really needed because you know you can have only 4 numbers).

The function `scanf_tetrad` takes the array as parameter.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void scanf_tetrad(int p[2][2])
{
        printf("Enter 4 numbers:");
        scanf("%d %d %d %d", &p[0][0], &p[0][1], &p[1][0], &p[1][1]);
}

int main()
{
        int ia[2][2];
        int i,j;

        scanf_tetrad(ia);

        printf("You entered: ");
        for (i=0; i < 2; i++)
                for(j=0; j < 2; j++)
                        printf("%d ", ia[i][j]);

        printf("\n");

        return 0;
}
```

Execution:

```
./tetrad
Enter 4 numbers:54634 456 7486743 4546
You entered: 54634 456 7486743 4546
```

Here is simple program to read multiple tetrads:

1. it firsts asks to enter the number of tetrad
2. it allocates a dynamic array `tt` which in array of tetrad arrays
3. it allocates each array tetrad in `tt`
4. it reads each tetrad array with the same above function
5. it displays the tetrad array items using a formula to access array item address [x,y] which  is `x * (number of columns) + y`. Note that this code may not be 100% C standard compliant.

metrad.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void scanf_tetrad(int p[2][2])
{
        printf("Enter 4 numbers:");
        scanf("%d %d %d %d", &p[0][0], &p[0][1], &p[1][0], &p[1][1]);
}

int main()
{
    int i,j, idx;
    int ttnb;
    int ***tt, **ctt;


    printf("Enter number of tetrad:");
    scanf("%d", &ttnb);

    tt = malloc(ttnb * sizeof (int [2][2]));
    if (tt == NULL)
    {
        perror("malloc");
        return 1;
    }

    for (idx=0; idx < ttnb; idx++)
    {
        tt[idx] = malloc(sizeof (int [2][2]));
        if (tt[idx] == NULL)
        {
            perror("malloc");
            return 1;
        }
    }


    for (idx=0; idx < ttnb; idx++)
    {
        scanf_tetrad((int (*)[2])tt[idx]);
    }

    printf("You entered:\n");
    for (idx=0; idx < ttnb; idx++)
    {
        printf("tetrad %d: ", idx);
        ctt = tt[idx];      
        for (i=0; i < 2; i++)
            for(j=0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                printf("%d ", *((int*)ctt + (i * 2) + j));
            }
        printf("\n");
    }


    return 0;   
}
```

Example of execution:

```
./mtetrad
Enter number of tetrad:4
Enter 4 numbers: 1 2 3 4
Enter 4 numbers:5 6 7 8 
Enter 4 numbers:9 10 11 12     
Enter 4 numbers:13 14 15 16
You entered:
tetrad 0: 1 2 3 4 
tetrad 1: 5 6 7 8 
tetrad 2: 9 10 11 12 
tetrad 3: 13 14 15 16
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!!It works very well .But i want the tetrad's input inside a loop,so i can give the tetrads multiple(N) times.

Comment: I have added a new example to read multitple tetrads in a loop.